# What is the expected value of the absolute value of a Wiener Process?

Tags: expectation, absolute-value

I am trying to show that the with a Wiener Process $w(t)$, then $\mathbb{E}[|w(t_1)w(t_2)|] = (\frac{2a}{\pi}) \sqrt{t_1 \cdot t_2} (\cos \theta + \theta \sin \theta)$, given $\sin \theta = \sqrt{\frac{t_1}{t_2}}$.

So I know that $R_x(t_1,t_2) = a\cdot\min(t_1,t_2)) =  \mathbb{E}[w(t_1)w(t_2)]$

I tried to take the approach that $|w(t)| = \sqrt{w(t)^2}$. But I still can't seem to solve it.

Comment: Can you identify the ***joint*** distribution of $(W(t_1), W(t_2))$?

Comment: Its a normal distribution with a zero mean and a variance of t.

Comment: What you said is the ***marginal*** distribution of $W(t)$.

Comment: By the way, what does $a$ stand for in your expression?

Comment: The distributions are independent so it would be N(0,0,t1,t2). a is simply provided as a parameter to the variance. So the variance should be at